# Authentication request is not processed when I try to log into my Symfony project while using a Windows 10 Ubuntu bash

Tags: php, bash, symfony

With my Symfony project, I am able to log in my project without any issue. Recently, I've installed the [Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and I wanted to start learning linux commands and using it to run my future projects. When starting my local symfony server in the Ubuntu bash, I use the following command:

```
bin/console server:run
```

However, when I try to log in after that, I get the following message:

```
Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.
```

This error has never appeared when I would start the project in the Windows Command Prompt. I assumed it would have to do with a built-in security issue with Symfony, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have php mysql installed on Windows, but not on the Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash. Make sure php and Mysql are installed on the Ubuntu bash as well.

Comment: This worked. I had php installed on my Ubuntu Bash, but not Mysql. Thank you.